# In .NET why does event connection order matter like this?

Tags: .net, events, delegates

```
using System;

static class Program
{
    static event Action A = delegate { };
    static event Action B = delegate { };

    static void Main()
    {
        A += B;
        B += ()=>Console.WriteLine("yeah");
        A.Invoke();
    }
}
```

This doesn't print anything, but if I swap the first two lines of Main, it does.

Answer (score 5):

Events are immutable, i.e. you get a copy when assigning, like integers

```
int a = 1;
int b = 2;

a += b; // a == 3
b += 1; // a is still 3
```

Comment: nice answer - perhaps in terms of terminology, it would be better to say "delegates are immutable" - *events* are just *accessors* (add/remove), so the concept of immutability does not really apply.

Answer (score 2):

A += B; is appending the list of delegates from B into A.
It is copying the contents of B, not a reference to B.

It is the same as:

```
A = (Action)System.Delegate.Combine(A, B);
```

So the order is definitely important.